# restrict data from select with Row-Level Security when updating

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I want to create an ordered list of labeltext, so I wrote the following initial script:
**Schema (PostgreSQL v10.0)**

```
create table tbl1 (
  uid text primary key /* user id */
);
create table tbl2 (
  uid text not null default current_setting('custom.setting.uid', true)::text,
  order_id int not null,
  labeltext text,
  foreign key (uid) references tbl1 (uid) on delete cascade
);

INSERT INTO tbl1 (uid) VALUES ('boom');
INSERT INTO tbl1 (uid) VALUES ('bang');
INSERT INTO tbl1 (uid) VALUES ('bash');

alter table tbl2 enable row level security;
  create policy all_order on tbl2 for all
    using (uid = current_setting('custom.setting.uid', true)::text)
    with check (uid = current_setting('custom.setting.uid', true)::text);

create or replace function tfn(text) returns int as $$
declare
tmp int;
begin
insert into tbl2(order_id, labeltext)
  select coalesce(
      (select order_id
        from tbl2
          order by order_id desc limit 1
      ),
      0
    ) + 1, $1
    returning order_id into tmp;
return tmp;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

set custom.setting.uid to 'boom';
show custom.setting.uid;
select tfn('foo');
select tfn('bar');
set custom.setting.uid to 'bang';
select tfn('baz');
```

`tfn` expected to get the greatest order_id for **current user** and insert some new labeltext with the increased order_id.
but however, the results look different:

```
**Query #1**

    select * from tbl2;

| uid  | order_id | labeltext |
| ---- | -------- | --------- |
| boom | 1        | foo       |
| boom | 2        | bar       |
| bang | 3        | baz       |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6NiCHaBvyWaac721AiHyJC/0)

expect row created by user *bang* to have *order_id* = 1, but actually...
**it's still able to select other user's *order_id* without restrictions**

How to use RLS to limit the selection of order_id when updating?
If this isn't doable with RLS, any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, row level security does not apply to the owner of the table.

If you want that, you got to

```
ALTER TABLE tbl2 FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

There are some other settings that may cause RLS not to be used:

- If the configuration parameter `row_security` is `off`.
- If the user is a superuser.
- If the user was created with `BYPASSRLS`.